# Cetificate Pinning. How do we handle the situation where a website is visited for the first time?

Tags: certificates, certificate-authority, certificate-revocation

What I essentially mean to ask is, how is the scenario where a user who visits a website for the first time (the certificate for the website is not pinned in the browser) handled ? Additionally how is revocation handled ?

Answer (score 2):

The way that trust on first touch is handled for pinning is by the use of Pre-load lists, where the certificate to pin against is loaded into the client software at distribution.

You can see more information about what domains Firefox has preloaded [here](https://wiki.mozilla.org/SecurityEngineering/Public_Key_Pinning#New_sites_pinned_in_Firefox_34)

Revocation with pinning is an interesting topic.  What I've seen suggested is that you pin two keys, one that your using live and a backup one that you keep offline.  That way if you need to revoke your main certificate you have a spare one to use.

Without that if you revoke your certificate you could be in a spot of bother depending on your customer base.

Answer (score 0):

Pinning is a security technique applied to any cryptographic element, mainly certificates and public keys. Mostly public keys as they can be reused to issue multiple of certificates.

Pinning ensures that the right and trusted CA (Certificate Authority), issued the certificate. So when you visit say, google.com the browser (i.e. Google Chrome), checks to see if the intermediate CA is a pinned certificate and if it is it marks as white-listed CA.

There is no clear solution to which certificate in the chain should be pinned, For now Chrome checks to see the intermediate one as its public key is embedded in the website's certificate.

Comment: Public Key Pinning Extension for HTTP (HPKP) reports pin-validation failures.